# My CSV file generated from powershell has spaces inserted in values

Tags: csv, powershell, append, spaces

This is about to drive me bananas.  I am creating a csv file in Powershell but the outputted values in the field have spaces inserted in them when I view.  Let me show the basic code and what happens.

```
$csvFile = [String]::Format("{0}mycsvfile.csv","e:\kerry\")
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $csvFile
$writer.WriteLine('{0},{1}',"field1","field2")
$writer.Flush()
$writer.Close()
$writer.Dispose()
"test field 1" + "," + "some val for field 2" | Out-File $csvFile -append
import-csv e:\kerry\mycsvfile.csv
```

...and my csv file can be seen in the [attached file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n2qR.jpg):

Any ideas?

Comment: ...sorry about the "enter image description here"  for my image link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those likely aren't spaces; `Out-File` defaults to Unicode, which uses 16 bits per character. Try `Out-File $csvFile -Append -Encoding Ascii`.

Comment: Right on!!!  This fixed it!  Thanks a trillion!  I DID manage a workaround while I was waiting using $writer.WriteLine.

Thanks again!!   You made me day! :)